# Why do retrieved Django models don't have the timezone set to its datetime?

Tags: django, timezone

I have a question about the way Django works with timezones.

In my settings I configure my timezone:

```
USE_TZ = True
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Amsterdam'  # At time of writing UTC+2
```

I have a model with a DateTimeField. I know that whenever Django saves this model in the timezone UTC regardless of timezone settings. I also know that whenever Django encounters a datetime without timezone (a naive datetime) it will assume it in the default time zone (in my case Amsterdam) and convert it to UTC upon saving. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/timezones/#interpretation-of-naive-datetime-objects

However, whenever I retrieve a model from the DB using Django, the DateTimeField will have a datetime that does not have a timezone. I know by specification that it is in UTC, but whenever I save my model back to the DB (after updating some fields) Django will see the datetime is naive and assume it is in the default timezone. In my case it keeps subtracting 2 hours from the datetime every time an object is updated.

So, whenever I do this.

```
A = MyModel.object.get(pk=1)
A.some_field = 10
A.save()
```

I will get a `RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received a naive datetime` and my timestamp got subtracted 2 hours.

I can solve this using

```
A = MyModel.object.get(pk=1)
A.date_time_field = A.date_time_field.replace(tzinfo=django.utils.timezone.utc)
A.some_field = 10
A.save()
```

But that seems not the way to go?

Comment: This is not standard Django behavior, so something about your setup is broken. You should look into (and add details about) your database and database adapter. And you might want to see if you can replicate this with a fresh Django project on the same system.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Thanks, I found that the field of postgresql did not had a timezone enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field of Postgresql responsible for this did not had timezone enabled.